# increase variable from within another block

Tags: c, fork, scope

I'm currently writing a simple C program to create a specified number of child-processes from the parent process, and I'm trying to keep track over how many of them that was actually successfully initiated by increasing the variable **active** every time a child-process was successful.

However, the stupid piece of #!%€ variable won't let me modify it.. I'm new to C (hence the simplicity and questionable usability of the program) and I'm having a bit of a problem understanding the different variable-scopes and when, and how you can modify them so that the new value sticks...

So, my questions is; how do I make the variable "active" increase by 1?

I've already made sure that the newChild() function returns 1 as it should, and other code within that if-statement works, so it's not that. And, I've also tried using pointers, but without success... :(

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <unistd.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <sys/wait.h>

main()
{
    printf("Parent CREATED\nRunning code...\n");

    // INITIATE Variables
    int children = 5;
    int active = 0;
    int parentID = getpid();

    // INITIATE Random Seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    // CREATE Children
    int i, cpid, sleepTime;

    for (i = 0; i < children; i++)
    {
        // Only let the parent process create new children
        if (getpid() == parentID)
        {
            // GET Random Number
            sleepTime = rand() % 10;

            // CREATE Child
            if (newChild(sleepTime) == 1)
            {
                // Mark as an active child process
                active++;
            }
        }
    }

    // CLEAN UP
    if (getpid() == parentID)
    {
        // Let the parent process sleep for a while...
        printf("Parent is now SLEEPING for 20 seconds...\n");
        sleep(20);
        printf("Parent is now AWAKE\nActive children: %d\n", active);

        // WAIT for Children
        int cpid, i;
        int status = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < active; i++)
        {
            // WAIT for Child
            cpid = wait(&status);

            // OUTPUT Status
            printf("WAITED for Child\nID: %d, Exit Status: %d\n", cpid, status);
        }

        printf("All children are accounted for.\nEXITING program...\n");
    }
}

int newChild(int sleepTime)
{
    // INITIATE Variable
    int successful = 0;

    // CREATE Child Process
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == -1)
    {
        // OUTPUT Error Message
        printf("The child process could not be initiated.");
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        // Mark child process as successfully initiated
        successful = 1;

        // OUTPUT Child Information
        printf("Child CREATED\nID: %d, Parent ID: %d, Group: %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp());

        // Let the child process sleep for a while...
        printf("Child %d is now SLEEPING for %d seconds...\n", getpid(), sleepTime);
        sleep(sleepTime);
        printf("Child %d is now AWAKE\n", getpid());
    }

    return successful;
}
```

Comment: Where are you checking the value of `active`?

Comment: I don't see a call to `fork()` in your program. Did you new that `fork` actually copies everything, including `active`? Both processes won't share memory by default, you have to use some other features, for example using a signal handler for `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: @Zeta I call `fork()` in the `newChild()` function, and yes, that's why I check the PID to make sure only the parent process can create new children

Comment: what does `newChild()` return?

Comment: @Tim: `1` if a child process could be forked, `0` otherwise. At least my magic 8-ball says so.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Further down the code (not included), but I've checked by setting the initial value of `active` and the code that checks the value actually gets it correctly, so it's not that either...

Comment: Please post the code to `newChild()`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman the function `newChild()` is not the problem as I've checked, and other code, like, for example, `printf("SUCCESSFUL");` worked just fine when I put it inside the if-statement.. so it's gotta be something with the actually incrementation of the variable active

Comment: The declaration and incrementation of `active` is correct by the C standard so the problem lies elsewhere

Comment: Seriously. Please post the code to `newChild()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three outcomes from calling fork() which your code is incorrectly condensing down to two:

1. A return value of -1 indicates that fork failed. This is an uncommon error condition.
2. A return value of 0 indicates that fork succeeded and you're now in the child process.
3. A return value of >0 indicates that fork succeeded and you're in the parent process.

Notice how cases 2 and 3 are both "successful". But your newChild() function returns 1 for case 2 and returns 0 for case 3. Instead what it should do is return 1 for case 3, and for case 2 it *shouldn't even return*. If you're in case 2 then you're in the child process and so you should just do your child process stuff and then exit, never returning to the caller.

```
if (pid == -1)
{
    // OUTPUT Error Message
    printf("The child process could not be initiated.");
}
else if (pid == 0)
{
    // OUTPUT Child Information
    printf("Child CREATED\nID: %d, Parent ID: %d, Group: %d\n", getpid(), getppid(), getpgrp());

    // Let the child process sleep for a while...
    printf("Child %d is now SLEEPING for %d seconds...\n", getpid(), sleepTime);
    sleep(sleepTime);
    printf("Child %d is now AWAKE\n", getpid());

    // This is the child process, so we should NOT EVEN RETURN from newChild().
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    successful = 1;
}
```

The key observation here is that when you call fork() your process is going to split into two separate processes that *both* continue executing from the point where fork() returns. The difference between them is that one will get a 0 return value and the other will get a >0 return value. The former is the child and the latter is the parent.

After fork() you now have two copies of the same code running, with two separate invocations of newChild() running, and with two separate copies of the `active` variable. After forking there are two of everything.

Comment: oooh, Thank you so much! New to the whole "multi-thread" thing as well, so haven't gotten used to thinking like that ^^ Worked perfectly! So, again, Thank you! :)

Comment: It's a really weird thing to wrap your mind around. The whole idea of forking took me a long time to completely understand. And for what it's worth, this is multi-processing not multi-threading. Threads share their global variables; processes each have their own copies. That's an important distinction to understand. In a way, threading is easier to understand... but it's a lot harder to master!